# why loop iterating 6 times but condition is given 5 times

Tags: c, loops

in my code according to for loop Condtion it is clear that it must iterate only 5 times from 0 to 4.
But it is taking 6 input from the user.
Why it is happening.
Please clear my doubt.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main() {
  int i, num;
  clrscr();
  printf("Enter 5 elements in the array\n");
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    scanf("%d\n", &num);
  }
  getch();
}
```

Comment: Please edit the code into your question (**not as an image**).

Comment: I just did your job and made your question readable.

Answer (score 1):

According to your code i think you are mixing up the inputs you request with the system pause created by the getch() function you call at the end. The getch() initiates a pause which you can easily mix up with your input prompts since during this pause, user input is possible though not considered.
I propose you introduce an instruction in the loop which indicates the line or some information so you can make the distinction.

Answer (score 1):

You have *two* problems regarding input.

The first is the `getch` call at the end of the program. But the other problem is the newline in the `scanf` format string

```
scanf("%d\n",&num);
```

When the [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) function sees a space in the format string (newline is considered a space in this context) then it will read and discard all spaces in the input. The problem with a trailing space in a format string is that to know when the spaces in the input ends, there must be some *non* space input as well.

So (almost) never have a trailing space (space, newline, carriage-return, tab) in a `scanf` format string.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this code wait 5 times user input is the `getch()` at the end.
It waits for the input of one character and probably used to prevent the shell window from directly closing after the program finshed.